# Why does Curl/Wget mess the encoding system of this web page?

Tags: html, curl, encoding, web, wget

For example, this page:

http://www.bilibili.tv/sitemap/sitemap-29.html

is encoded in utf-8. But when I use `wget` or `curl` to save it as a file, such as:

```
curl http://www.bilibili.tv/sitemap/sitemap-29.html > 29.html
```

Then use a web browser to open it. I found that it can't recognize the right coding system. Does anyone have idea about this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a web browser and directly try to open the document from file system, this differs from accessing it via the www.bilibili.tv webserver. Next to the HTML content itself, a webserver sends several HTTP responses, where Content-Type is one of them. Most probably it will have sent in this case:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

which will instruct the browser that the document it receives is HTML, encoded in UTF-8. This information is missing when accessing the same HTML content via filesystem. The browser will try to infer the charset from the content itself, but this can fail, as happened in your case.